# Problema con FileReader java

Tags: java

necesito orientacion, necesito leer el contenido de un archivo .txt , estoy utilizando FileReader para realizarlo, el problema es que mi programa no lee todo el archivo completo, lo lee casi a partir de la mitad. les muestro mi codigo esperando alguien pueda orientarme.
gracias

```
package LecturaDeArchivosUam;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ClaseFileReader {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      String texto= "";
      try {
          BufferedReader br;

          FileReader fr =new FileReader("Romeo.txt");
          br= new BufferedReader(fr);
          System.out.println("El texto contenido en el archivo ");

          String linea=br.readLine();
          while(linea !=null) {
              System.out.println(linea);
              linea=br.readLine();
          }
          br.close();
      }catch(IOException ioe) {System.out.println("\n\nError al abrir o guardar el archivo: ");
             ioe.printStackTrace();
      }catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println("\n\nError al leer de teclado: ");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }


  }
}
```

Comment: ¿es muy grande el tamaño?, podrías agregar que contiene el .txt

Answer (score 0):

No me parece que pueda existir un problema en el código para poder leer el archivo, de hecho lee desde la primera linea e imprime su contenido.

Pienso que probablemente pueda ser la configuración de la pantalla de salida donde imprimes el contenido del archivo.

Veo que usas `BufferedReader`, te sugiero definir un "buffer size" para cuestiones de performance:

```
br= new BufferedReader(fr, 1024);
```

---

Realiza este cambio en tu código:

```
  String texto= "";
  try {
      BufferedReader br;

      FileReader fr =new FileReader("Romeo.txt");
      br= new BufferedReader(fr, 1024);
      System.out.println("El texto contenido en el archivo ");

      String linea=br.readLine();
      while(linea !=null) {
          System.out.println(linea);
          linea=br.readLine();
      }
      br.close();
  }catch(IOException ioe) {System.out.println("\n\nError al abrir o guardar el archivo: ");
         ioe.printStackTrace();
  }catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("\n\nError al leer de teclado: ");
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```